# asp.net mvc5 when login to an account can't create or upload file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

there was no problem with the local debugging.But when I uploaded the program to the hosting, In the case of no login account, run this Controller:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/1.txt"), "123", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
ViewBag.content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/1.txt"));
```

it can create a file to the root directory, but when I login an account, run the Controller again, it can't create a file.It said **that access to the path "XX" is denied.**
is the hosting problem or the code?
when i upload the mvc5 simple membership website to the hosting, the problem again.

```
public ClaimsIdentity CreateIdentity(User user, string authenticationType)
    {
        ClaimsIdentity _identity = new ClaimsIdentity(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        _identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName));
        _identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.UserID.ToString()));
        _identity.AddClaim(new Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider", "ASP.NET Identity"));
        return _identity;
    }
```

```
var _identity = userService.CreateIdentity(_user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
```

If it's a question of the hosting folder permissions, when I not logged in, it can 't create a file, right?

Comment: check the permissions of the folder in the hosting environment... may be this will help